# Cómo añadir un nodo en una posición concreta JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Alguien sabe como añadir un nodo en una posición concreta?
Tengo que añadir un párrafo en el `body`, y como se haría para que añada el párrafo en una posición concreta del DOM?? Ahora mismo añade los párrafos al final del `body`, pero si quiero añadirlo delante de otro párrafo, ¿Cómo lo hago?

```js
function creaParrafos() {
 //Obtenemos los valores escritos en los tipo textos
 var posicion = document.getElementById("posicion").value;
 var texto = document.getElementById("valor").value;

 //Creamos un elemento, que sera el parrafo
 var elementoNodo = document.createElement("p");

  //Creamos un nodo de texto, que será el que recojamos del tipo texto
  var nodoTexto = document.createTextNode(texto);

  //Y lo añadimos al parrafo
  elementoNodo.appendChild(nodoTexto);

  //Y añadimos el elemento donde querramos introducirlo, ya sea un div o el body
  document.body.appendChild(elementoNodo);
}
```

```html
<p>posicion: </p><input type="text" id="posicion">
<p>texto: </p><input type="text" id="valor">
<input type="button" onclick="creaParrafos()" value="Crear">
```

Answer (score 1):

Listo, lo que hice fue definir el nodo padre, agregar los elementos hijos de a cuerdo a la posición que se indique usando la función **insertBefore** para poder agregarlo en la posición correspondiente y para esto tuve que recorrer los nodos del padre, obtener el id y este id se le asignó al elemento hijo antes de agregarlo al DOM.

```js
function creaParrafos() {
 var posicion = document.getElementById("posicion").value;
 var texto = document.getElementById("valor").value;
 var padre = document.getElementById("contenedorPadre");
    var hijos = parseInt(padre.children.length);

 var elementoNodo = document.createElement("p");
 var nodoTexto = document.createTextNode(texto);
 var id = parseInt(hijos+1);
 elementoNodo.appendChild(nodoTexto);
 elementoNodo.setAttribute("id", id);

 if (hijos === 0){
      padre.appendChild(elementoNodo);
 }else{
   if(posicion){
     if(posicion<=hijos){
       for(i=0;i<hijos;i++){
         if(i === posicion-1){
              var actual = document.getElementById(padre.children[i].id);
        padre.insertBefore(elementoNodo, actual); 
         }
       }
     }else if (parseInt(parseInt(posicion)-hijos) <=1){
       padre.appendChild(elementoNodo); 
     }else{
       alert("te pasaste!!")
     } 
   }else{
     alert("introduce la posición.")
     document.getElementById("posicion").focus();
   }
 }
}
```

```html
    <p>posicion: </p>
    <input type="number" id="posicion">
    <p>texto: </p>
    <input type="text" id="valor">
    <input type="button" onclick="creaParrafos()" value="Crear">
    <div id="contenedorPadre">
      
    </div>
```

Saludos!

Comment: muchisimas gracias!! era justo lo que queria, pero no se poque haces un setAttribute a elementoNodo, que hace esa parte??

Comment: Le agrego el atributo ID al elemento hijo <p> que se agrega, ya que el 'insertBefore' lo requiere, para indicarle antes de que elemento(por ID) voy a agregar mi nuevo elemento <p>

Answer (score 0):

Pueden haber diferentes formas de hacerlo , plantearé una donde haré uso de dos clases adicionales como la `posición` y `newP` que se agregará al nuevo elemento , además de emplear el método [insertBefore()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Node/insertarAntes) para insertar en una determinada "posición" . Un pequeño cambio en el `HTML` sería cambiar el tipo del `input` por `number`.  *(La explicación  está incluida en el código , para el ejemplo se añadió al texto la posición para que sea más visible el resultado)*

```js
function creaParrafos() {
  var posicion = parseInt(document.getElementById("posicion").value);
  var texto = document.getElementById("valor").value;
  var body = document.body;
  //Creamos un elemento, que sera el parrafo
  var elementoNodo = document.createElement("p");
  elementoNodo.classList.add(posicion, "newP");
   //Creamos un nodo de texto, que será el que recojamos del tipo texto
  var nodoTexto = document.createTextNode(posicion +" : " +texto);
   //Y lo añadimos al parrafo
  elementoNodo.appendChild(nodoTexto);
  //Obtenemos los párrafos  añadidos
  var elems = document.getElementsByClassName("newP");
  //Variables adicionales para saber si se agrego el elemento o si
  // la posición ya está ocupada.
  var seagrego= false;
  var posicionocupada=false;
  //iterams sobre los elementos p
  for (var i = 0; i < elems.length && !seagrego && !posicionocupada ; i++) {
    // si la posición es  diferente a la clase que tiene 
    // como valor la posición en que se inserto
    if(parseInt(elems[i].className)!==posicion){
        //Si es mayor , entonces podemos insertar antes de ese elemento
        if(parseInt(elems[i].className) > posicion){
          //insertamos antes del elemento iterado. elems[i]
          body.insertBefore(elementoNodo,elems[i]);
          //seteamos la bandera
          seagrego=true;
        }
    }
    else{
      //seteamos la bandera, para saber que la posición está ocupada
      posicionocupada= true;
    }
  }
  //si no está la posición ocupada , preguntamos si no se agregó 
  // si cumple añadimos al final ,
  //body.children.length-1  (evitamos insertar después de la etiqueta scripts 
  // que también se obtiene con children.)
  if(!posicionocupada ){
     if(!seagrego) body.insertBefore(elementoNodo,body.children[body.children.length-1]);
  }
  else{
    //caso contrario avisamos al usuario que la posición ya Existe
    alert("Ya Existe un Elemento en Dicha Posición");
  }

}
```

```html
<p>posicion: </p><input type="number" id="posicion" >
<p>texto: </p><input type="text" id="valor">
<input type="button" onclick="creaParrafos()" value="Crear" >
```

Si desea no tener en cuenta las posiciones repetidas y solo desplazar hacía abajo los elementos, tendría que hacer una pequeña modificación en el código.

```js
function creaParrafos() {
  var posicion = parseInt(document.getElementById("posicion").value);
  var texto = document.getElementById("valor").value;
  var body = document.body;
  //Creamos un elemento, que sera el parrafo
  var elementoNodo = document.createElement("p");
  elementoNodo.classList.add(posicion, "newP");
   //Creamos un nodo de texto, que será el que recojamos del tipo texto
  var nodoTexto = document.createTextNode(posicion +" : " +texto);
   //Y lo añadimos al parrafo
  elementoNodo.appendChild(nodoTexto);
  //Obtenemos los párrafos  añadidos
  var elems = document.getElementsByClassName("newP");
  //bandera adicionales para saber si se agrego el elemento
  var seagrego= false;
  //iterams sobre los elementos p
  for (var i = 0; i < elems.length && !seagrego  ; i++) {
      //Si es mayor , entonces podemos insertar antes de ese elemento
      if(parseInt(elems[i].className) >= posicion){
        //insertamos antes del elemento iterado. elems[i]
        body.insertBefore(elementoNodo,elems[i]);
        //seteamos la bandera
        seagrego=true;
      }
    
  }
  if(!seagrego) body.insertBefore(elementoNodo,body.children[body.children.length-1]);
}
```

```html
<p>posicion: </p><input type="number" id="posicion" >
<p>texto: </p><input type="text" id="valor">
<input type="button" onclick="creaParrafos()" value="Crear" >
```

Comment: esta bien, pero si una posicion esta ocupada debe desplazar a los demas hacia abajo, pero muchas gracias entendi mucho tu codigo

Comment: @alvaroguerrerovallejo actualicé mi respuesta con esa consideración. me alegra que le haya ayudado. Saludos.